# Перестроить код на основе команды loop

Tags: циклы, ассемблер

Нужно перестроить код. Вместо ;!!! перестроить код на основе команды loop

```
title cycle
model small
stack 100h
.data
n equ 5
mas db n dup (?)
sum db ?
.code
start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
xor dx,dx
xor bx,bx
xor cx,cx
mov bx, offset mas
m1: inc cx
mov [bx],cx
inc bx
cmp cx,5
jb m1
;!!!
m2: dec cx
dec bx
add dl, [bx]
jcxz m3
jmp m2
;!!!
m3: mov sum, dl
mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
end start
```

Comment: Сорри,перестроить на основе команды loop

Comment: И вывести в консоль значение 15

Answer (score 1):

По идее достаточно заменить две команды

```
jcxz m3
jmp m2
```

на одну `loop m2` и убрать `dec cx` (т.к. `loop` сам уменьшает `cx`). Изначально можно было эти два перехода написать одной инструкцией: `jcxnz n2` - т.е. переход, если `cx` не равен 0.

Comment: Спасибо,а как вывести на консоль число 15?

Comment: Я бы сказал, не очень просто. В цикле делить на 10 с остатком, к остатку прибавлять символ '0' - последовательно получатся цифры числа. Если частное равно нулю, значит число закончилось. Вот тут пример есть: https://fasmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/022-vyvod-chisel-na-konsol/

Comment: А вообще, если всегда 15 нужно выводить, выведите как строку. Если нужно именно результат вычислений, см. ссылку выше.